NumPy: get a matrix of distances between values
If I have a set of points:
points = np.random.randint(0, 11, size=10)
print(points)

Output:
[ 5  4  9  7  4  1  2 10  4  2]

And if I want to get a matrix representing the distance from each point to each other point, I can do so like this:
def get_diff_array(values):
    dX = values - values[0]
    tmp = [dX]
    for i in range(1, len(dX)):
        tmp.append((dX - dX[i]))
    return np.array(tmp)

print(get_diff_array(points))

Output:
[[ 0 -1  4  2 -1 -4 -3  5 -1 -3]
 [ 1  0  5  3  0 -3 -2  6  0 -2]
 [-4 -5  0 -2 -5 -8 -7  1 -5 -7]
 [-2 -3  2  0 -3 -6 -5  3 -3 -5]
 [ 1  0  5  3  0 -3 -2  6  0 -2]
 [ 4  3  8  6  3  0  1  9  3  1]
 [ 3  2  7  5  2 -1  0  8  2  0]
 [-5 -6 -1 -3 -6 -9 -8  0 -6 -8]
 [ 1  0  5  3  0 -3 -2  6  0 -2]
 [ 3  2  7  5  2 -1  0  8  2  0]]

Is there a faster NumPy-specific way to calculate this? Currently it takes approximately 0.44 seconds for 10k points, which seems slow. This is really just a learning question to try to understand NumPy better.

You can use values[:, np.newaxis] - values[np.newaxis, :]:
import numpy as np

def diff(A):
    return A[:, np.newaxis] - A[np.newaxis, :]

print(diff(np.random.randint(0, 11, size=10)))

Prints
[[  0  -7  -8  -3  -6  -6  -4  -5 -10  -3]
 [  7   0  -1   4   1   1   3   2  -3   4]
 [  8   1   0   5   2   2   4   3  -2   5]
 [  3  -4  -5   0  -3  -3  -1  -2  -7   0]
 [  6  -1  -2   3   0   0   2   1  -4   3]
 [  6  -1  -2   3   0   0   2   1  -4   3]
 [  4  -3  -4   1  -2  -2   0  -1  -6   1]
 [  5  -2  -3   2  -1  -1   1   0  -5   2]
 [ 10   3   2   7   4   4   6   5   0   7]
 [  3  -4  -5   0  -3  -3  -1  -2  -7   0]]


Wow, simple and ~4x faster. I have a lot to learn about broadcasting. Thank you.

You can use outer
np.subtract.outer(points, points).transpose()

which gives
array([[ 0, -1,  4,  2, -1, -4, -3,  5, -1, -3],
       [ 1,  0,  5,  3,  0, -3, -2,  6,  0, -2],
       [-4, -5,  0, -2, -5, -8, -7,  1, -5, -7],
       [-2, -3,  2,  0, -3, -6, -5,  3, -3, -5],
       [ 1,  0,  5,  3,  0, -3, -2,  6,  0, -2],
       [ 4,  3,  8,  6,  3,  0,  1,  9,  3,  1],
       [ 3,  2,  7,  5,  2, -1,  0,  8,  2,  0],
       [-5, -6, -1, -3, -6, -9, -8,  0, -6, -8],
       [ 1,  0,  5,  3,  0, -3, -2,  6,  0, -2],
       [ 3,  2,  7,  5,  2, -1,  0,  8,  2,  0]])

